# Division of teams on the basis of skill point

Tags: java, algorithm

I am trying to put n players having different skill point(ranging from 100-3000) into r teams such that overall skill in each team is as close as possible to every other team.

I first sorted the players in descending order of skill points and top r players were put into each team. Now the team with lowest skill point(iterating and calculating sum) gets the top player remaining.

For eg.

- A 600
- B 550
- C 400
- D 250
- E 220
- F 200
- G 150
- H 140

For 2 teams, result will be:

- Team A{600,250,220,150}= 1220
- Team B{550,400,200,140}= 1290

In another approach each team gets a player from top and a player from bottom.

- Team A{600,140,400,200}=1340
- Team B{550,150,250,220}=1170

So here 1st approach was better, but for different set of data sometimes approach 2 is optimum and sometimes approach 1 is optimum.

Is there any specific algorithm to do this? I tried to read Microsoft's TrueSkill algorithm, but it was way too complex.

Comment: I believe you should remove the "java" tag, since the quesiton is about a general problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to score each combination of players. I'm going to cheat and use python here:

```
from itertools import combinations

players = [600, 550, 400, 250, 220, 150, 140]

scores = {}

for i in range(1, int(len(players)/2)):
    for c in combinations(players, i):
        scores[c] = abs(sum(c) - sum([p for p in players if p not in c]))

print sorted(scores.items(), key=lambda x: x[1])[0]
```

prints: `((600, 550), 10)`

Edit: Didn't recognize this as a hard problem right away.

Comment: I'll recognize this next time, thanks.  It gets slow at 20 players, very slow at 25.

Comment: @mcdowella Just to explain I took r=2. Problem can have any number of teams.

Answer (score 0):

Like mcdowella mentioned in a comment, this problem, as stated, is *np-hard*. A classic approach would be [Integer Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming).

The following implementation uses the [Julia](http://julialang.org/) programming language and the [JuMP](https://github.com/JuliaOpt/JuMP.jl)  library as modelling tool. The Integer/Mixed-Integer-Programming solver used is [cbc](https://projects.coin-or.org/Cbc), but a commercial solver as [Gurobi](http://www.gurobi.com/) may used too (only 2 lines of code-change needed!). Besides Gurobi, all the mentioned tools are open-source!

### Code

```
using JuMP
using Cbc

# PARAMS
N_PLAYERS = 15
N_TEAMS = 3
LOWER_SKILL = 100
UPPER_SKILL = 3000

# RANDOM INSTANCE
SKILL = Int[]
for p = 1:N_PLAYERS
    push!(SKILL, rand(LOWER_SKILL:UPPER_SKILL))
end

# MODEL
m = Model(solver=CbcSolver())
bigM = sum(SKILL)^2  # more tight bound possible

# VARS
@defVar(m, x[1:N_PLAYERS, 1:N_TEAMS], Bin)  # player-team assignment vars
@defVar(m, 0 <= tsum_pos[1:N_TEAMS,1:N_TEAMS] <= bigM)  # abs-linearization: pos-part
@defVar(m, 0 <= tsum_neg[1:N_TEAMS,1:N_TEAMS] <= bigM)  # abs-linearization: neg-part

# CONSTRAINTS 
# each player is assigned to exactly one team 
for p = 1:N_PLAYERS
    @addConstraint(m, sum{x[p,t], t=1:N_TEAMS} == 1)
end

# temporary team sum expresions
team_sums = AffExpr[]
for t = 1:N_TEAMS
    @defExpr(y, SKILL[p] * sum{x[p,t], p=1:N_PLAYERS})
    push!(team_sums, y)
end

# errors <-> splitted abs-vars equality
for t1 = 1:N_TEAMS
    for t2 = 1:N_TEAMS
        if t1 != t2
            @addConstraint(m, (team_sums[t1] - team_sums[t2]) == (tsum_pos[t1,t2] - tsum_neg[t1,t2]))
        end 
    end 
end

# objective
@setObjective(m, Min, sum{tsum_pos[i,j] + tsum_neg[i,j], i=1:N_TEAMS, j=1:N_TEAMS})  # symmetry could be used

# SOLVE
tic()
status = solve(m)
toc()

# OUTPUT
println("Objective is: ", getObjectiveValue(m))
println("Solution: ")
println("Player skills: ", SKILL)
for p = 1:N_PLAYERS 
    for t = 1:N_TEAMS 
        if getValue(x[p,t]) > 0.5
            println("player ", p, " in team ", t)
        end 
    end
end

for t=1:N_TEAMS
    sum_ = 0
    for p=1:N_PLAYERS
        if getValue(x[p,t]) > 0.5
            sum_ += SKILL[p]
        end
    end
    println("team: ", t, " -> ", sum_)
end
println(sum(SKILL))
```

This modelling uses some [linearization-trick](http://orinanobworld.blogspot.de/2012/07/modeling-absolute-values.html) to model absolute values, as needed for a L1-norm-based error like you described in your post!

### Output

```
elapsed time: 9.785739578 seconds
Objective is: 28.00000000000063 # REMARK: error is doubled because of symmetries which could be changed
Solution: 
Player skills: [2919,1859,1183,1128,495,1436,2215,2045,651,540,2924,2367,1176,334,1300]
player 1 in team 3
player 2 in team 1
player 3 in team 3
player 4 in team 1
player 5 in team 3
player 6 in team 2
player 7 in team 2
player 8 in team 1
player 9 in team 1
player 10 in team 1
player 11 in team 3
player 12 in team 2
player 13 in team 2
player 14 in team 2
player 15 in team 1
team: 1 -> 7523
team: 2 -> 7528
team: 3 -> 7521
22572
```